# Unsure of my options, Multi-blog?

Tags: multisite, users

I'm looking to create a system where people can sign up and post content to my blog. A bit like each user having their own mini blog within my main one. The blog site is based on car projects that all fall under one general niche, having subaru engine swaps.

What I'd like to achieve is a system where a user creates a project folder/category before they are able to post content, for example if I wanted to post about my own project I would have to create a category for that like 1972 VWRX Bug.

Then each time I wanted to update something about that build/project it would be assigned to that project, allowing any visitor to the website the ability to view the project from start to finish.

By doing it this way I would hope that I could also create just a gallery that pulls all photos from the project, or a blog page showing all the posts/images and content.

What options do I have here, is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of searching around, it occurred to me that what I was trying to do was essentially to create a social network. Having search for Wordpress Social Network plugins I discovered and am using Buddypress.